# Selecting at least x consecutive values that are the same and removing the end points of these values

Tags: r

I have the following data set:

```
A <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0)
B <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)
C <- c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)
df <- cbind(A, B, C) 
> df
      A B C
 [1,] 1 0 0
 [2,] 1 0 1
 [3,] 1 1 1
 [4,] 1 1 1
 [5,] 1 1 1
 [6,] 1 1 1
 [7,] 1 0 1
 [8,] 1 1 1
 [9,] 1 1 1
[10,] 1 1 0
[11,] 0 1 0
[12,] 1 1 0
[13,] 0 0 1
```

I want to do two things to each column: first, I want to change all the 1s that are within two places of a 0 to a 0. Then, I want to select regions of columns where there are at least four consecutive 1s; in other words, if a 1 appears that is not in a consecutive string of four or more 1s, it will become a 0. The resulting data set should look like this:

```
> df
      A B C
 [1,] 1 0 0
 [2,] 1 0 0
 [3,] 1 0 0
 [4,] 1 0 1
 [5,] 1 0 1
 [6,] 1 0 1
 [7,] 1 0 1
 [8,] 1 0 0
 [9,] 0 0 0
[10,] 0 0 0
[11,] 0 0 0
[12,] 0 0 0
[13,] 0 0 0
```

What’s the best way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another possible approach using `base` functions. Explanation inline with code.

```
apply(df, 2, function(x) {
    #identify 0 locations, create indices 2 places away from these locations 
    #and set these to 0
    idx <- unique(unlist(lapply(which(x==0L), `+`, -2L:2L)))
    x[idx[idx > 0L & idx <= length(x)]] <- 0L        

    #create run length encoding, filter for those with value=1 but less than 4 
    #and set those lengths to 0
    r <- rle(x)
    r$values[r$lengths < 4L & r$values==1L]  <- 0L
    inverse.rle(r)
})
```

output:

```
      A B C
 [1,] 1 0 0
 [2,] 1 0 0
 [3,] 1 0 0
 [4,] 1 0 1
 [5,] 1 0 1
 [6,] 1 0 1
 [7,] 1 0 1
 [8,] 1 0 0
 [9,] 0 0 0
[10,] 0 0 0
[11,] 0 0 0
[12,] 0 0 0
[13,] 0 0 0
```

Comment: Awesome. In order for the output to have the same column lengths as the input, it is necessary to delete the last 2 rows of the output in this case. Thanks!

Comment: Why does this function add two extra rows in the resulting dataframe, and is it possible to write a function where the resulting dataframe has the same number of rows as the original dataframe?

Comment: @DavidMoore, sorry the `:2L` was extending the idx beyond the `length(x)`. I have filtered them away.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `lag` and `lead` for the comparisons (for the first part).

Here's an example using your data (this is on the original version before any edits to your question):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
df <-
as.tibble(df) %>%
  mutate(A_lag=lag(A)) %>%
  mutate(B_lag=lag(B)) %>%
  mutate(C_lag=lag(C)) %>%
  mutate(A_lag2=lag(A,2)) %>%
  mutate(B_lag2=lag(B,2)) %>%
  mutate(C_lag2=lag(C,2)) %>%
  mutate(A_lead=lead(A)) %>%
  mutate(B_lead=lead(B)) %>%
  mutate(C_lead=lead(C)) %>%
  mutate(A_lead2=lead(A,2)) %>%
  mutate(B_lead2=lead(B,2)) %>%
  mutate(C_lead2=lead(C,2)) %>%
  as.data.frame()

a <- df[,c(1,4,7,10,13)]
b <- df[,c(2,5,8,11,14)]
c <- df[,c(3,6,9,12,15)]

df <- data.frame(A=apply(a,1,min,na.rm=T),
           B=apply(b,1,min,na.rm=T),
           C=apply(c,1,min,na.rm=T)
)
```

This leads to an intermediate result table that looks like this:

> ```
>    A B C
> 1  1 0 0
> 2  1 0 0
> 3  1 0 0
> 4  1 0 1
> 5  1 0 1
> 6  1 0 1
> 7  1 0 1
> 8  1 0 0
> 9  0 0 0
> 10 0 1 0
> 11 0 1 0
> 12 0 1 0
> 13 0 1 0
> ```

The result from this step complies with the your logic for it.

The next step however it seems that your words ask for one thing - keep only 1's that are in a column-wise block of at least four 1's - but your example shows something slightly different.

Your example output shows column `B` as all 0's, even though the last 4 rows of it are all 1's as a result of the logic from the earlier step.

I've created some code that follows the logic you specified. If you forgot to include a detail or otherwise wanted something slightly different this should hopefully get you close enough (otherwise please let me know in a comment).

```
# You could do it without a for loop if need be
myfun <- function(x) {
  for(i in 1:length(x)){
    x[i] <- ifelse((sum(x[i:(max(0,i-3))]) == 4) | (sum(x[i:(min(length(x),i+3))]) == 4),1,0)
  }
  return(x)
}

apply(df,2,myfun)
```

Comment: You're right - sorry! I just edited column B my question to fix it. I will take a look at the coding later today.